# Get null use System.getenv() in gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

```
def CATALINA_HOME = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME")
task t << {
    println CATALINA_HOME
}
```

`CATALINA_HOME` is null when I run with idea (double click t from Gradle Project panel), but when `gradle t` is executed in terminal I get a correct path.
It seem this is only happen in OSX (my version is 10.11.14 El Capitan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has problems with recognizing environment variables on OS X (not sure if on other systems as well). Please have a look at this [post](http://depressiverobot.com/2016/02/05/intellij-path.html) - it should solve the problem (some time ago I had similar issue and found it very useful).

Since the linked page no longer exists you can find it in the archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190304092735/http://depressiverobot.com/2016/02/05/intellij-path.html). Thanks @AlexeyStepanov!

Comment: the website doesn't work. Use archive https://web.archive.org/web/20190304092735/http://depressiverobot.com/2016/02/05/intellij-path.html

Answer (score 0):

Want to add, that sometimes it insufficient for Intellij Idea to configure Run/Debug Configuration option of Environment variable.

Instead you need to set them in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Runner -> Environment variables